# TensorFlow: Efficient way to compute reduce-sum block-matrix multiplications

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I have the following equation:

[image: block-element]

Where M is a [Dx3] matrix and V is a [DxD] matrix. Each of these forms a [3x3] block in a larger [3Kx3K] matrix, indexed by i, j. For now, I'm wondering if anyone has come across doing a reduce-sum of this form in TensorFlow - I'm still getting used to the API structure!